# como puedo solucionar el Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on boolean en INNER JOIN?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, join

Tengo una práctica de `INNER JOIN` y me sale el error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on boolean
```

y no me muestra los campos de la base.

Mi código es éste:

```
<?php
$query="
    SELECT Al.id_alumno, Al.nombre, Al.edad,
       Carr.nombre_carrera, Carr.area_carrera,
       Gru.nombre_grupo, Gru.turno
    FROM alumnos Al
    INNER JOIN carreras Carr ON Al.id_carrera = Carr.id_carrera
    INNER JOIN grupos Gru ON Al.id_grupo = Gru.id_grupo
";
$consulta=$conexion->query($query);
/* aqui es donde me sale el erro en el fetch y lo he cambiado por mysql_fetch_array y mysqli_fetch_array pero sale el mismo error */
while ($fila=$consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo'
    <tr>
    <td>'.$fila['id_alumno'].'</td>
    <td>'.$fila['nombre'].'</td>
    <td>'.$fila['edad'].'</td>
    <td>'.$fila['nombre_carrera'].'</td>
    <td>'.$fila['area_carrera'].'</td>
    <td>'.$fila['nombre_grupo'].'</td>
    <td>'.$fila['turno'].'</td>
    </tr>
    ';
}
?>
```

Comment: Por favor, modifica la pregunta e incorpora la estructura de las tablas en SQL con algún registro para las pruebas (phpMyAdmin,Exportar) y así podamos montar un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Aquí se explica mucho mejor [ask]. Bienvendo a [so]

Answer (score 1):

Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow.

De acuerdo al Manual de PHP, `query` devuelve `FALSE` cuando hay algún error, por lo que el mensaje de error que estás teniendo indica que el resultado de `query` es un booleano, o sea es `FALSE` porque la consulta falló.

Conviene siempre escribir un código que controle las posibles eventualidades, para capturar este tipo de fallos.

Aquí te dejo una propuesta:

```
<?php 
    if ( !$conexion ){
        $txtOut="No hay conexión";  
    } else {
        $query="
            SELECT a.id_alumno, a.nombre, a.edad,
               c.nombre_carrera, c.area_carrera,
               g.nombre_grupo, g.turno
            FROM alumnos a
            INNER JOIN carreras c ON a.id_carrera = c.id_carrera
            INNER JOIN grupos g ON a.id_grupo = g.id_grupo
        ";
        if ( !$consulta=$conexion->query($query) ){
            $txtOut="Hubo un error en la consulta: ".$conexion->errorInfo[2];
        } else {
            $txtOut="<table>";
            while ($fila=$consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                $txtOut.=
                "<tr>
                <td>$fila[id_alumno]</td>
                <td>$fila[nombre]</td>
                <td>$fila[edad]</td>
                <td>$fila[nombre_carrera]</td>
                <td>$fila[area_carrera]</td>
                <td>$fila[nombre_grupo]</td>
                <td>$fila[turno]</td>
                </tr>
                ";
            }
            $txtOut.="</table>";
        }
    }
    echo $txtOut;
?>
```

Me he permitido también usar *alias*  más simples para las tablas. Generalmente se usa una alias de una letra o dos, sólo que cuando lo veas sepas a cual de las tablas se refiere. Poner alias muy largos hace el código demasiado verboso y más complicado de analizar, sobre todo en consultas largas.

Espero te sea de utilidad.